# Porque o operador bitwise and está me retornando 0 neste caso?

Tags: javascript

Bom, segundo o site do [Imasters](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/conheca-os-operadores-bitwise-bit-bit) eles definem a utilidade do operador bitwise and como:

> O operador & ( Bitwise AND ) compara dois valores utilizando suas representações binárias, retornando um novo valor. Para formar esse valor de retorno, cada bit é comparado, retornando 1( true ) quando ambos os bits forem iguais a 1( true ); caso contrário, retorna 0( false ).

Até ai tudo bem, mas notem nesse exemplo:

```js
let n1 = 1; // 00110001
let n2 = 2; // 00110010

console.log(n1 & n2);
```

O exemplo acima tem o retorno `0` (`false`), isso porque `1` tem a representação em binário `00110001` e o `2` tem representação em binário `00110010`, então ambos não são iguais, mas no exemplo abaixo vai retornar `1` (`true`), isso porque ambos contém a mesma representação em binário:

```js
let n1 = 1; // 00110001
let n2 = 1; // 00110001

console.log(n1 & n2);
```

Mas no exemplo abaixo ele vai retornar `0` (`false`):

```js
let n1 = 0; // 00110000
let n2 = 0; // 00110000

console.log(n1 & n2);
```

Porque o retorno é `0` (`false`) se ambos contém a mesma representação em binário?

Comment: Uma dica pra ver a representação binária de um número: `n1.toString(2)`. Se quiser com os zeros à esquerda, pode fazer `n1.toString(2).padStart(8, "0")`

Comment: hkotsubo, mas o que este comando faz `padStart(8, "0")`

Comment: Coloca os zeros na frente, completando com no máximo 8 caracteres.

Comment: Obrigado você é o cara!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem vários conceitos errados na sua pergunta:

1) a representação binária de 1 não é `00110001`, mas sim `00000001`, mesmo para 2 `00000010`), precisa rever como funciona a base binária e como converter;

2) os operadores *bitwise* não retornam um `boolean` mas um novo número, logo nunca será true ou false a resposta;

3) o link que passou parece não explicar bem a operação, tanto que te confundiu, sugiro o *mozilla.org*, veja esse link: [https://developer.mozilla.org/](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

As operações de *bitwise* comparam os números bit a bit e resultam num novo número. 
A operação *bitwise or* `|` comprar os bits, e retorna 1 sempre que algum dos bits comparados for 1, e a operação *bitwise and* `&` retorna 1 sempre que ambos os bits forem 1.

Vejamos um exemplo prático para perceber melhor isso. Vamos usar os números 1, 2 e 3:

```
let n1 = 1; // 00000001
let n2 = 2; // 00000010
let n3 = 3; // 00000011
```

Veja ao lado a representação binária de cada um. Se compararmos n1 e n2, vamos ter os seguintes resultados:

```
let n1 = 1; // 00000001
let n2 = 2; // 00000010  
-----------------------  
bitwise or |   00000011 = 3 (nesse caso, o penúltimo e o último bits são um)
bitwise and &  00000000 = 0 (neste caso, não houve ambos bits 1)
```

No *bitwise or*, os bits 7 e 8 são 1, em **pelo menos um dos números**, por isso resultou o `00000011`.
No *bitwise and*, apesar de ter bits 1, não houve nenhum bit que fosse 1 em ambos (n1 tem o bit 8 em 1, e n2 tem o bit 7).

Agora comparando n2 e n3:

```
let n2 = 2; // 00000010
let n3 = 3; // 00000011
----------------------------  
bitwise or |   00000011 = 3 (neste caso, mesmo resultado da comparação anterior)  
bitwise and &  00000010 = 2 (neste caso, como ambos os bits 7 estão em 1, resulta 1)
```

Aqui, no *bitwise and*, irá retornar 00000010, ou seja, o número 2. Aqui o exemplo prático:

```js
let n1 = 1; // 00000001
let n2 = 2; // 00000010
let n3 = 3; // 00000011

console.log(n1 | n2);
console.log(n1 & n2);
console.log(n2 | n3);
console.log(n2 & n3);
```

Comment: desculpe é que estou aprendendo agora JavaScript, no caso que você falou "a representação binária de 1 não é 00110001, mas sim 00000001", então os número, por exemplo, que eu tacar nesse site não vão ser binários? https://www.invertexto.com/codigo-binario

Comment: @draw Esse site codifica **texto**, então se digitar `1` ele vai interpretar como um caractere, cujo valor na [tabela ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com) é 49, que em binário se torna 110001

Comment: valeu ajudou bastante

Comment: como o @hkotsubo mencionou esse site converte texto para binário, e não números, para converter números pode usar uma calculadora, ou algum outro site online, como esse por exemplo: https://clevert.com.br/t/pt-br/base-convert

Comment: Valeu, @Ricardo Pontual, esse site vai me ajudar bastante, tudo de bom pra você!

Comment: se a resposta respondeu sua dúvida não esqueça de aceitar ;)

Comment: Sim, esqueci! :)